# help with magento cloud

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

My team has build an **e-commerce** project on **magento cloud**. But our tutor is asking for the whole project **to be downloaded** so that he can review it on his local host and give us the feedback.

Can anyone help me to sort out this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the project files then you can clone the project to your local machine using git clone.

If you need a working copy locally, then you should follow the documentation on setting up a local environment:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/cloud/setup/first-time-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

You can back up the code via `bin/magento setup:backup --code` which will take the code and the configurations. 
For help on taking the back up's: `bin/magento setup:backup --help`